# ExitPolicy to local machine

Tags: configuration, exit-policies

There is a comment in the [`torrc` man page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) that exit policies can target the local machine or private networks, like say :

```
ExitPolicy accept 127.0.0.1:80
ExitPolicy reject private:*
```

Does anyone actually do this?  How would one actually exploit it?

There are no `ip` address limits specified in the consensus according to :

```
egrep "^p6? " /var/lib/tor/cached-microdescs | grep ':'
```

I suppose this means "Tor does not bother to list such exits", or their operators somehow suppress inclusion, or nobody does this.

If someone configures this, how does one use the access the local exit created?  Does the server need to set `Nickname foobar` or whatever.  And the client need to set `AllowDotExit 1` and then access `localhost.foobar.exit:80`?  Is there an easier way?

Is this a viable approach to making a private exit useful for [pinning an exit for a specific site](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/gmail-and-gtalk-over-tor-suggestions)?

Also, what is the difference between `ExitPolicy` and `ReachableAddresses`?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [ExitPolicyRejectPrivate torrc option](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitPolicyRejectPrivate). As the ExitPolicy man page entry says...

```
These addresses are rejected by default [...] unless
you set the ExitPolicyRejectPrivate config option to 0.
```

It's very much not suggested but if your goal in all this is to use your own relay as a single-hop exit see [AllowSingleHopCircuits](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#AllowSingleHopCircuits)

Comment: Yes, you disable ExitPolicyRejectPrivate obviously, but how does that answer the questions of : Does anyone use private exits?  How to use them effectively?  Can the be indexed?  I should rephrase the question focusing on the last point.

Comment: Not many people allow exiting to localhost since it's a security risk. You can figure out which relays allow it by getting the server descriptors, then checking their exit policies (https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/mirror_mirror_on_the_wall.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a partial answer although browsing the tor source code, although reading the man page more closely would've sufficed.  lol

There is a `FetchUselessDescriptors` option that, if you set it, causes Tor to fetch the old style full descriptors, not just the current microdescriptors.  At that point, there are many reject lines for specific domains, but not currently any accept lines :

```
grep ":\*" /var/lib/tor/cached-descriptors
```

There is a script at `contrib/or-tools/exitlist` that helps you find exits for specific IP ranges.